# XML parse from URL into ListView

Tags: android, xml, parsing, nullpointerexception, token

I'm getting an unexpected token error and null pointer exception on the below activity and I cannot find out where the problem could be. I am parsing the below URL which is an XML file containing provisional Golf player details. I had it working when I had less nodes in the file but now I am receiving the token error which causes null pointer. Can anyone point out where it goes wrong?

```
public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/90179278/helloworld.xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_PLAYER = "player"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "playername";
    static final String KEY_DOB = "dob";
    static final String KEY_WEIGHT = "weight";
    static final String KEY_HEIGHT = "height";
    static final String KEY_HANDED = "handed";
    static final String KEY_COUNTRY = "country";
    static final String KEY_BIO = "bio";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_PLAYER);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_DOB, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DOB));
            map.put(KEY_WEIGHT, parser.getValue(e, KEY_WEIGHT));
            map.put(KEY_HEIGHT, parser.getValue(e, KEY_HEIGHT));
            map.put(KEY_HANDED, parser.getValue(e, KEY_HANDED));
            map.put(KEY_COUNTRY, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COUNTRY));
            map.put(KEY_BIO, parser.getValue(e, KEY_BIO));
            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DOB, KEY_WEIGHT, KEY_HEIGHT, KEY_HANDED, KEY_COUNTRY, KEY_BIO }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.dob, R.id.weight, R.id.height, R.id.handed, R.id.country, R.id.bio });

        setListAdapter(adapter);



    }
}
```

Output:

03-30 11:07:48.060: E/Error:(1742): Unexpected token (position:TEXT ï»¿@1:4 in java.io.StringReader@b514c300)

03-30 11:07:48.070: D/AndroidRuntime(1742): Shutting down VM

03-30 11:07:48.070: W/dalvikvm(1742): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4e15908)

03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.xmlparsing/com.androidhive.xmlparsing.AndroidXMLParsingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)

03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)

03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742):     at com.androidhive.xmlparsing.AndroidXMLParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.java:47)

03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)

03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)

03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)

03-30 11:07:48.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1742):     ... 11 more

Comment: Edit your question and add the logcat showing the errors.

Comment: There you go, I'm new to Android development so don't know much about Logcat

Comment: Post the lines under `Caused by:` in the logcat as well.

Comment: Okay I found out that the problem is something called a byte order mark at the start of a XML file . I don't know how to fix it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem was a BOM or "byte order mark" that was present at the start of the file. In notepad++ it can be easily removed by selecting the encoding option and choosing encode in UTF-8 without BOM option from the drop down menu.

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?592741-Byte-Order-Mark-found-in-UTF-8-File